# R - Converting date into POSIXct (Previously working)

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I'm running into issues with some scripts that were previously working fine. I'm not certain where the error is coming from, or whether something changed within R on how it handles dates and times.

An example dataset would be:

```
data <- data.frame( "Timestamp" = c(seq(round_date(as.POSIXct("2023-04-05 HST"), unit="10 minutes"),  round_date(as.POSIXct("2023-04-06 HST"), unit="10 minutes"), by = 600)), "Value" = 5)
```

The script then summarizes the data like so:

```
thirty.min = data %>% group_by(Timestamp = cut(Timestamp, "30 min")) %>%
     summarise(Value = sum(Value))
```

I would then convert the resulting Timestamp column into a character, then a POSIXct format. However, this results in all midnight values being turned into NAs.

```
thirty.min$Timestamp <- as.character(thirty.min$Timestamp)
thirty.min$Timestamp <- as.POSIXct(thirty.min$Timestamp, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "HST")
```

This ultimately results in NAs being placed where the time should be midnight, 00:00.

I'm not certain where the issue is occurring, as this script has worked fine in the past. It hasn't been used since around July of this year, if that is any help.
I believe either the group_by function would maintain the POSIXct format previously, where it is now being converted into a factor - or, the missing 00:00 in the midnight cells are somehow resulting in an error when trying to convert into POSIXct.

Comment: `cut(data$Timestamp, "30 min")` is causing the issue - that gives a character string as output, not a date.

Comment: I like the pattern of `group_by(Timestamp = floor_date(Timestamp, "30 min"))` for this sort of thing.

Comment: also, I did not get errors running this code as is